# flash as3 - get data from DOM via actionscript 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript-3, dom

I've been trying to use various canvas / svg libraries such as raphaeljs to create animations / visualizations based on data passed into the DOM via AJAX, but they never seem as powerful as I want them to be in terms of animation. I've also tried things such as processing.js, but the communication back and forth across the DOM isn't very good - it's easy for processing to reach out to javascript, but not vice versa. So I was wondering if there was some technology that might combine these two facets (animation and communication with the DOM) - or whether there was a good way for Flash to interact back and forth with a constantly changing DOM, preferrably via javascript / jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you use JS functions to manipulate the DOM, right? If so, you can connect AS3 and JS through the [ExternalInterface API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).